# how to set a maximum width for the website and make it scrollable

Tags: html, asp.net, css, width

I have a page in my webapp that contain 3 textbox side by side as they all display important information. However, if i were to reduce my browser size, my twitter bootstrap navbar and my slideshow header will follow the size of the browser and fit 100% as mentioned in my codes

```
<div id="Slideshow">
<img src="image/s1.jpg" name="slide" style="width:100%; height:150%">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var step = 1
function slideit() {
    document.images.slide.src = eval("image" + step + ".src")
    if (step < 5)
        step++
    else
        step = 1
    setTimeout("slideit()", 2500)
}
slideit()
//-->
</script>
</div>

<div id="twitterbootstrap">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="brand" href="#">iPolice's Menu</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="AdminAddAccount.aspx">AddAccount</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="AdminDropAccount.aspx">Drop Account</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="AdminEditProfile.aspx">Edit Account</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="AdminColdStorage.aspx">Cold Account</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="AdminReportCheck.aspx">Report Check</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="AdminLogout.aspx">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see i set my slideshow as width:100%. However as for my table and textbox, this is how it is

```
<table width="100%">
        <tr>

            <td id="admintaskdetail">
                <b>Details </b>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbdetails" runat="server" Height="120px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="400px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>

            <td id="admintaskpropertydetail">
                <b>Property Details:</b>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbproperty" runat="server" Height="120px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="400px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>



            <td id="admintasksuspectdetail">
                <b>Suspect Details:</b>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbsuspect" runat="server" Height="120px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="400px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>


        </tr>
    </table>
```

Unfortunately, this is how my website look. My navbar and slideshow are exactly the same width.

[image]

In order to counter that, i tried to wrap my navbar, header and the contents under a id called wrapper and code like this which didnt work either

```
#wrapper {
width:80%;
overflow:scroll;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

May i know the correct way on how to set a maximum width for my website and then make the overflow part scrollable after the maximum width? I was hoping to make my navbar and twitterbootstrap navbar to stop following the browser after a particular width by wrapping them under a wrapper id which didnt work as well.

Regards.

Been trying for days and still failed to get it out.

Comment: You can place your textboxes inside bootstrap row of span 4 , so that those align automatically to your screen size.. is that wat u r looking for?I guess the fixed 400px width is causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Panel control with ScrollBars

```
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="100%" ScrollBars="Both">

<table width="100%">
    <tr>

        <td id="admintaskdetail">
            <b>Details </b>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbdetails" runat="server" Height="120px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="400px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td id="admintaskpropertydetail">
            <b>Property Details:</b>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbproperty" runat="server" Height="120px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="400px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td id="admintasksuspectdetail">
            <b>Suspect Details:</b>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbsuspect" runat="server" Height="120px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="400px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: because i have a updatepanel and a scriptmanager. Do i wrap my updatepanel and scriptmanager under the panel control and set the width?

Comment: Place panel into UpdatePanel.

Comment: then placed other into Panel

Comment: However i got one problem, why do i have a vertical scroll-bar at the side of my body(gridview and textbox) after adding the panel control? And when i drag the vertical scroll-bar, my entire body begin to shake and disappear. It only re-appear back to it's original position after i click the body background.

Comment: Placed only table into panel

Comment: To maintain position of scrollable Panel : http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewfrederick/archive/2008/03/04/maintain-scroll-position-after-asynchronous-postback.aspx

Comment: Is it possible for me to have your email to discuss this topic?

Comment: I'm still having problem especially with my gridview. When i reduce my browser size, the panel just follow the width of the browser as i set it 100%. http://imgur.com/f90o2ZJ However as for my gridview, when it reaches a certain length, it just stops moving. Therefore, my gridview and textbox will be apart from each other. How do i make my textbox stop moving whenever my gridview stop moving? This is exactly how my webapp look like. I tried putting the panel into the textbox but it became worse.

Comment: You must use another panel to GridView. Panel with certain height and width , and Gridview with 100% width.

Comment: Panel must be scrollable.